# How do I use chain rule for higher derivatives in several variables?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function from unit ball $B\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable $n$ times for large $n$.

Let $\mathbf{a}$ be a point(vector) in the unit ball, fix a non-zero vector $\mathbf{u}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow B$  be the line $\gamma(t)=\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{u}$.

Then consider $g(t)=f\circ \gamma(t)$.

I want to know expression for $g^{(k)}(t)$. For $k=1$, we can use Chain rule and say
$$
g'(t)=Df_{\gamma(t))}D\gamma_{t}=\nabla f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{u})\cdot \mathbf{u}.
$$
But, I was unable to see the application of Chain rule or anything else to evaluate $g''(t)$ from this one.

How can I proceed for $g''(t)$?

**Note:** I am using only the definition of $\nabla$ with no properties; one may state it if needed in the evaluation of higher order derivatives.

Comment: $g'$ also is of the form $F\circ\gamma$ with $F=$ ... [hint]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g''(t) = D_t (g'(t)) = D_t (\nabla f (\mathbf a + t \mathbf u) \cdot \mathbf u) = \nabla^2 f (\mathbf a + t \mathbf u) \cdot \mathbf u$$